# How to store the result of an executed function and re-use later?

Tags: python, python-2.7

E.g., I have:

```
def readDb():
    # Fetch a lot of data from db, spends a lot time
    ...
    return aList

def calculation():
    x = readdb()
    # Process x
    ...
    return y
```

In the python interpreter,
each time I run `calculation()` it takes a lot of time to re-read the database, which is unnecessary.
How can I store the result from `readdb()` to avoid this reducdant process?

**Edit:**
I found a similar question here but I don't quite know the answer
[Save functions for re-using without re-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230869/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python - this solves a more general problem.

Comment: You dont want to have an updated copy of the database each time ?

Comment: @NPE Not really related. That deals only with Dynamic Programming.

Comment: @AshRj: The technique is far more widely applicable than dynamic programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def readDb():
    ... #Fetch a lot of data from db, spends a lot time
    return aList

def calculation(data):
    x=data
    ...process x...
    return y

data = readDb()

calculation(data)
calculation(data)
calculation(data)
```

This will only hit the database once.

Basically, you want to save the results of readDb() to a seperate variable which you can then pass to calculation().

Answer (score 5):

Write a simple decorator:

```
class memo(object):
    def __init__(self, fun):
        self.fun = fun
        self.res = None
    def __call__(self):
        if self.res is None:
            self.res = self.fun()
        return self.res

@memo
def readDb():
    # ... etc
    return aList
```

For more general solutions, look here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498245-lru-and-lfu-cache-decorators/.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer for modern Python**

For anyone still searching for how to do this, the standard library `functools` includes a decorator function [`@functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) to do this.

For example (from the docs):

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def get_pep(num):
    'Retrieve text of a Python Enhancement Proposal'
    resource = 'http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-%04d/' % num
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(resource) as s:
            return s.read()
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        return 'Not Found'
```

This would store the last `32` calls to `get_pep` and when it is called with the same argument, the cached value will be returned.